# Pod time-limit in Kubernetes job -- .spec.activeDeadlineSeconds per pod

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl

As explained in the [Kuberenetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup) on the topic of jobs:

> The `activeDeadlineSeconds` applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches `activeDeadlineSeconds`, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become `type: Failed` with `reason: DeadlineExceeded`.

However, what I want to do is limit the time of each *pod*. If a pod takes too long, I want it to fail, but I want the other pods to continue, and for the job to create more pods if necessary.

I'll explain a bit about my task, just to make the problem crystal clear. The job consists of taking items from a Redis database, where the database serves as a sort of queue. Each pod processes one item (well, the number might vary). If a pod takes too long processing an item, I want it to fail. However, the other pods should continue, and the job should continue creating pods and retrieving more items from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case seems identical to [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/) from the kubernetes docs.
As you said, `activeDeadlineSeconds` is not the parameter you should be using here.

I'm not sure why do you want the pod to fail if it can't process an item in a given time frame. I see a few different approaches that you can take here, but more info on the nature of you problem is required to know which one to take. 
One approach for solving your issue would be setting the job parallelism to the number of pods you'd like to run concurrently and set this behaviour in the code itself -

- If the issue delaying the processing is transient, you would probably want to terminate the current transaction, keep the item in your queue and restart handling the same item
- If the same item has failed x times, it should be removed from the queue and pushed to some kind of dead letter queue to await troubleshooting at a later point in time

Another approach would be to fanning out the messages in the queue in a way that will spawn a worker pod for each message, same as [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#single-job-starts-controller-pod) depicts.
Choosing this solution will indeed cause every pod taking too long to process the item to fail, and if you set the `restartPolicy` of the pods you create to `never` you should have a list of failed pods on your hands that correspond to the number of failed processed items.

Having said all that, I don't failing the pods is the right approach here, and that keeping track of failed processing events should be done using instrumentation, either by container logs or metrics.

Comment: The reason it looks like the _Fine Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue_ example is because I used it as a template :)

Comment: I think you're probably right that it is best to program this behavior into code it self.

Comment: Since you seem curious why I want pods to fail if they're not done in a given time-frame, I'll elaborate on the use-case. I'm working with large-scale data analysis, and want to mimic the behavior of batch scheduling frameworks like SLURM and Torque, and I want to be able to define a _walltime_. In my experience, walltime is a required parameter in these systems. You have to estimate your expected walltime. Essentially, a job is queuing for resources, and if an analysis is taking too long, you want to release these resources so that others may use them.

Comment: There are frameworks to implement these types of things more robustly in Kubernetes, for example [kube-batch](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kube-batch), but we haven't had the time to implement something like this, so I'm doing things more manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help @YaronIdan. I guess there's no easy solution here, just have to think hard.